# I want to check the values of two selection field and then make a button invisible

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I want to check the values of two selection field and then make a button invisible.I tried like this :

> Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="orchid_sale_order_cancel_request_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale_order_cancel_request</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <button name="action_cancel" position="after">
                <button string="Cancel Request" type="object" name="cancel_request" attrs="{'invisible':['&amp;',('od_dms','!=','sale'),('state','!=','sale')]}"/>
             </button>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Here `od_dms` and `state` are the two selection fields.I want to make the button `action_cancel` visible only when both `od_dms` = `sale` and `state` = `sale`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your button, `attrs` should be:

```
attrs="{'invisible':['|',('od_dms','!=','sale'),('state','!=','sale')]}"
```

Comment: @vbt Odoo uses [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) for its condition statement. More specifically, `invisible` will be determined by a list of 3 elements, 1 is condition operator, 2 & 3 are tuples. That is similar to `od_dms != 'sale' or state != 'sale'` in the Python language. Further reading: https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/full-list-of-search-operators-46716